# Parse pandas (multi)index to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have multi-index df as follows

```
                x  y
id  date            
abc 3/1/1994  100  7
    9/1/1994   90  8
    3/1/1995   80  9
```

Where dates are stored as str.

I want to parse date index. The following statement

```
df.index.levels[1] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.levels[1])
```

returns error:

```
TypeError: 'FrozenList' does not support mutable operations.
```

Comment: Please, next time asking pandas question, consider following [this excellent guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on making your examples reproducible (like one in my answer).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As mentioned, you have to recreate the index:

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels([df.index.levels[0], pd.to_datetime(df.index.levels[1])])
```

Answer (score 2):

One cannot modify `MultiIndex` in-place, so we have to recreate it. To do so, we use `get_level_values` to obtain multiindex levels as `Series`, then apply  `pd.to_datefime`, then reconstruct multiindex from two levels.

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('abc', '3/1/1994'), ('abc', '9/1/1994')],
                                 names=('id', 'date'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2]}, index=index)
print(df.index.get_level_values(level=1).dtype)
# object

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([index.get_level_values(level=0),
                                      pd.to_datetime(
                                          index.get_level_values(level=1))])
print(df.index.get_level_values(level=1).dtype)
# datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify it in-place. You can use [pandas.MultiIndex.map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.map.html) to create a new index and then assign it:

```
new_tuples = df.index.map(lambda x: (x[0], pd.to_datetime(x[1])))
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_tuples, names=["id", "date"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) with argument `level`

```py
df.index = df.index.set_levels(pd.to_datetime(df.index.levels[1]), level=1)
# or if you want to use the level name
df.index = df.index.set_levels(pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values('date')), level='date')
```

```
print(df)

                  x  y
id  date
abc 1994-03-01  100  7
    1995-03-01   90  8
    1994-09-01   80  9
```